# Covariance question: A non squared matrix possible?

Tags: matrices, statistics

I have an academic economic paper that says the following:

$$q_r = \operatorname{Cov}(rx,v')\lambda$$

$$(14 \times 1)=(14 \times 4)(4 \times 1)$$

My vector $q_r$ is of size $14 \times 1$, my matrix $rx$ is size $T \times 14$, and my matrix $v$ is of size $T \times 4$. I don't have the value of $\lambda$.

How can I get a covariance matrix of size 14 $\times$ 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $(i,j)$ entry of the matrix is the covariance of the $i$'th column of $rx$ and the $j$'th column of $v$.

Comment: Yes I believe so this is correct. Thanks!